# Asterisk automatic incoming call answering

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to learn ASterisk PBX and i have a problem that i did not saw in any tutorial.

I want to have and extension to automatically anser the call and transfert to extension 101 or 102 depending on the user selection from the softphone keyboard or voice. How can i implement that?

```
[default]
Exten => 101,1,Answer
Exten => 101,n,NoOp(Test101)
Exten => 101,n,Dial(SIP/101,12,r)
Exten => 101,n,VoiceMail(101@interno-ipca)
Exten => 101,n,Hangup()

Exten => 102,1,Answer
Exten => 102,n,NoOp(Test102)
Exten => 102,n,Dial(SIP/102,12,r)
Exten => 102,n,VoiceMail(102@interno-ipca)
Exten => 102,n,Hangup()
```

Comment: sip.conf is the file where you have to define context for sip clients. I think that is not pointing to "default" context which may be problem. post your sip.conf and extension.conf both for better clarification

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "depending on the user selection"? Most phones have a "DnD" feature that when enabled will tell the pbx that extension is "busy" immediately. You could tell your dialplan to always try to dial 101, and depending on the result of that, either try to dial 102 (if 101 has enabled DnD on the phone) or go to voicemail (if DnD is not set and 101 didn't answer). A common mistake is to always go to voicemail after the call finishes, but you should check the DIALSTATUS variable to make sure this is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want to anwser any call you can use

```
exten => _X,1,Answer()  
exten => _X,2,Read($Number,,[max digits])
exten => _X,3,Dial(SIP/$Number)
```

You can use [max digits], otherwise asterisk waits until the maximum of digits is reached, or you end the typing with "#"